# Could anybody comment on this code? Do you think it's thread safe and generally valid?

Tags: asynchronous, locking, async-await

Could you, please, look at the code below and give me your comments? My major concern is that normally await is forbidden to be used inside the lock, so what I did instead I repeatedly used Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit. To me it looks fine. If an exception happens in the first Monitor.Enter/Exit block finally will release the object on the first thread. If it happens on the second block it should be normally released on the second thread. await is used in between Monitor.Enter/Exit (or in other words locks). To clarify one other thing, I need to protect with critical section checking and changing the flag and adding/removing values to the LinkedList.

```
  public async Task EventAsync(CancellationToken objToken) {
     Monitor.Enter(_CompletionQueue);
     try {
        if(_Signaled) {
           _Signaled = false;
        }
        else {
           var objCancelCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
           using(objToken.Register(() => objCancelCompletion.SetResult(true))) {
              var objCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
              _CompletionQueue.AddLast(objCompletion);
              Monitor.Exit(_CompletionQueue);
              Task<bool> objTask = await Task.WhenAny(objCompletion.Task, objCancelCompletion.Task);
              Monitor.Enter(_CompletionQueue);
              if(objTask == objCancelCompletion.Task) {
                 _CompletionQueue.Remove(objCompletion);
              }
           }
        }
     }
     finally {
        if(Monitor.IsEntered(_CompletionQueue)) {
           Monitor.Exit(_CompletionQueue);
        }
     }
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it's best to avoid any thread-affine synchronization primitives (including `lock`, `Monitor`, `ManualResetEvent`, etc) when writing asynchronous code. `SemaphoreSlim` is a basic `async`-compatible replacement for `lock` and `Semaphore`.

From a wider perspective, there's almost definitely a better (higher-level) solution than a queue of `TaskCompletionSource`. Both Reactive Extensions and TPL Dataflow provide more comprehensive (and thoroughly tested) abstractions for problems like this, and if you need something lower-level, my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) has a complete collection of `async`-compatible primitives (based on [Stephen Toub's blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx)).